# Exponential of complex variable

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the equivalent to 
" $(e i)^z$ " , where i is the imaginary "i" and z is a variable (maybe a complex one) ?
(I'm thinking in a possible symmetry with $e^{iz}$)

Comment: Do you perhaps want to mean $(e^i)^z$ instead of $(ei)^z$?

Comment: No. I want to mean $(ei)^{z}$ not $e^{iz}$.

Comment: Why not directly $i^z$?

Comment: $i^x$ seems interesting to x $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, I think that a curve generated is a circumference. But to x $\in$ $\mathbb{I}$ ? What curve result of this ?

Comment: Note that f(x) -the image - is plotted in a $\mathbb{R}$ $x$ $\mathbb{I}$ plane.

Comment: I think that $(ie)^{x}$ generates a circumference as $e^x$ to x $\in$ $\mathbb{I}$. The difference between the two curves is only the "phase" - I guess.

Comment: If I multiply a real by "i", I get a number in the $\mathbb{I}$ set. But if I multiply "i" by a real number, I get a number in the same set $\mathbb{I}$. If I multiply two numbers in the $\mathbb{I}$ set, a get another number in the $\mathbb{R}$ set, the same does not occur between two numbers in the $\mathbb{R}$ set. So, the symmetry between the $\mathbb{R}$ set and $\mathbb{I}$ set does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you advance

> $$(ie)^z = e^{z\ln(ei)}=e^{z(\ln(e)+i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi i)  } = e^{z(1 + \frac{i\pi}{2} - 2k\pi )  } = \dots,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.   $$

Comment: >$$(ie)^z = e^{z\ln(ei)}=e^{z(\ln(e)+i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi i)  } = e^{z(1 + \frac{i\pi}{2} - 2k\pi )  } = e^z . e^\frac{i\pi}{2} . e^{-\frac{2k}{\pi}} \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.   $$